# How can i call just first result from forelse loop in laravel like (array_key_first)?

Tags: php, laravel

`@forelse($locations as $key => $value)`

```
  $result = $query->get();

   $locations = $result->pluck('name', 'id');

    if ($show_all) {
        $locations->prepend(__('report.all_locations'), '');
    }
```

instead of all locations, I want a single location/first location to be displayed

Full View Code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @forelse($locations as $key => $value)
        <div class="box box-solid">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">@lang('sale.location'): {{$value}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-th-green text-center table-striped add_opening_stock_table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>@lang( 'product.product_name' )</th>
                                    <th>@lang( 'lang_v1.quantity_left' )</th>
                                    <th>Unit Cost - تكلفة الوحدة)</th>
                                    @if($enable_expiry == 1 && $product->enable_stock == 1)
                                        <th>Exp. Date</th>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($enable_lot == 1)
                                        <th>@lang( 'lang_v1.lot_number' )</th>
                                    @endif
                                    <th>Subtotal - المجموع الفرعي</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
@php
    $subtotal = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($product->variations as $variation)
    @if(empty($purchases[$key][$variation->id]))
        @php
            $purchases[$key][$variation->id][] = ['quantity' => 0, 
            'purchase_price' => $variation->default_purchase_price,
            'purchase_line_id' => null,
            'lot_number' => null
            ]
        @endphp
    @endif

@foreach($purchases[$key][$variation->id] as $sub_key => $var)
    @php

    $purchase_line_id = $var['purchase_line_id'];

    $qty = $var['quantity'];

    $purcahse_price = $var['purchase_price'];

    $row_total = $qty * $purcahse_price;

    $subtotal += $row_total;
    $lot_number = $var['lot_number'];
    @endphp

<tr>
    <td>
        {{ $product->name }} @if( $product->type == 'variable' ) (<b>{{ $variation->product_variation->name }}</b> : {{ $variation->name }}) @endif

        @if(!empty($purchase_line_id))
            {!! Form::hidden('stocks[' . $key . '][' . $variation->id . '][' . $sub_key . '][purchase_line_id]', $purchase_line_id); !!}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          {!! Form::text('stocks[' . $key . '][' . $variation->id . '][' . $sub_key . '][quantity]', @format_quantity($qty) , ['class' => 'form-control input-sm input_number purchase_quantity input_quantity', 'required']); !!}
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            {{ $product->unit->short_name }}
          </span>
        </div>
    </td>
<td>
    {!! Form::text('stocks[' . $key . '][' . $variation->id . '][' . $sub_key . '][purchase_price]', @num_format($purcahse_price) , ['class' => 'form-control input-sm input_number unit_price', 'required']); !!}
</td>

@if($enable_expiry == 1 && $product->enable_stock == 1)
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('stocks[' . $key . '][' . $variation->id . '][' . $sub_key . '][exp_date]', !empty($var['exp_date']) ? @format_date($var['exp_date']) : null , ['class' => 'form-control input-sm os_exp_date', 'readonly']); !!}
    </td>
@endif

@if($enable_lot == 1)
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('stocks[' . $key . '][' . $variation->id . '][' . $sub_key . '][lot_number]', $lot_number , ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']); !!}
    </td>
@endif
    <td>
        <span class="row_subtotal_before_tax">{{@num_format($row_total)}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        @if($loop->index == 0)
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs add_stock_row" data-sub-key="{{ count($purchases[$key][$variation->id])}}" 
                data-row-html='<tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ $product->name }} @if( $product->type == "variable" ) (<b>{{ $variation->product_variation->name }}</b> : {{ $variation->name }}) @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-sm input_number purchase_quantity" required="" name="stocks[{{$key}}][{{$variation->id}}][__subkey__][quantity]" type="text" value="0">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                            {{ $product->unit->short_name }}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm input_number unit_price" required="" name="stocks[{{$key}}][{{$variation->id}}][__subkey__][purchase_price]" type="text" value="{{@num_format($purcahse_price)}}">
    </td>

    @if($enable_expiry == 1 && $product->enable_stock == 1)
    <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm os_exp_date" required="" name="stocks[{{$key}}][{{$variation->id}}][__subkey__][exp_date]" type="text" readonly>
    </td>
    @endif

    @if($enable_lot == 1)
    <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stocks[{{$key}}][{{$variation->id}}][__subkey__][lot_number]" type="text">
    </td>
    @endif

    <td>
        <span class="row_subtotal_before_tax">
            0.00
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'
    ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    @else
        &nbsp;
    @endif
            </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="@if($enable_expiry == 1 && $product->enable_stock == 1 && $enable_lot == 1) 5 @elseif(($enable_expiry == 1 && $product->enable_stock == 1) || $enable_lot == 1) @else 3 @endif"></td>
                                    <td><strong>Total Amount - المبلغ الإجمالي: </strong> <span id="total_subtotal">{{@num_format($subtotal)}}</span>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="total_subtotal_hidden" value=0>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                        </table>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--box end-->
        @empty
            <h3>@lang( 'lang_v1.product_not_assigned_to_any_location' )</h3>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using [collection first](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first)

Comment: @forelse($locations as $key => $value) ->first(); .?

Comment: $firstItem = $locations->first()